# fileUpload no carga nada, no arroja errores

Tags: c#, asp.net

Este fileUpload, no carga el archivo, no arroja error, no hace nada, solo blink! y se suponé que cargó, en las 4 labels que puse para verificar la carga tampoco arroja nada, solo aparece:

Label Label Label Label

```
if (uplFilesComitePQR.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                int adjuntoPQRComite = lastIdenty;
                string fileExt = "";
                fileExt = Path.GetExtension(uplFilesComitePQR.FileName).ToLower();
                if (fileExt == ".doc" || fileExt == ".docx" || fileExt == ".pdf" || fileExt == ".xlsx")
                {
                    if (uplFilesComitePQR.PostedFile.ContentLength < 1500000)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(uplFilesComitePQR.FileName);
                        uplFilesComitePQR.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/PQR_adj/id_pqr_" + adjuntoPQRComite + fileExt));
                        Label1.Text = "Carga de archivo: Correcta!";
                    }
                    else
                        Label2.Text = "Carga de archivo: el archivo debe tener un tamaño inferior a 1.5mb!";
                }
                else
                    Label3.Text = "Carga de archivo: el tipo de archivo seleccionado no está permitido, por favor vuelva a intentarlo!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label4.Text = "Carga de archivo: el archivo no pudo ser cargado ha ocurrido el siguiete error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64053/discussion-between-vulpex-and-lois6b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, despúes de descubrir que es el debug y el punto de interrupción me aparecía el  `if (uplFilesComitePQR.HasFile) = false` así que revisando lo raro que tenía mi código era que el formulario está divido por 4 paneles, y el fileupload está en el panel 3 y el botón de envío final en el panel 4.

```
//.cs
     public void panelUno(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pnlStepOne.Visible = true;
            this.pnlStepTwo.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepThree.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepFour.Visible = false;
        }
    public void panelDos(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pnlStepOne.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepTwo.Visible = true;
            this.pnlStepThree.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepFour.Visible = false;
        }
    public void panelUno(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pnlStepOne.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepTwo.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepThree.Visible = true;
            this.pnlStepFour.Visible = false;
        }
    public void panelUno(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pnlStepOne.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepTwo.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepThree.Visible = false;
            this.pnlStepFour.Visible = true;
        }
//.aspx
    <asp:panel Id="pnlUno">(...)</asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel Id="pnlDos">(...)</asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel Id="pnlTre"><asp:FileUpload(...)></asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel Id="pnlCua">(...)</asp:Panel>
```

Así que lo que hice fue pasar el fileupload al panel 4 y que se adjunte el archivo sólo al final cuando el usuario haya revisado que la encuesta de los paneles anteriores está correcto y así evito subir el archivo en el paso 3 sin que el usuario haya enviado el paso 4. estó me deja el código así:

```
//.aspx
    <asp:panel Id="pnlUno">(...)</asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel Id="pnlDos">(...)</asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel Id="pnlTre">(...)</asp:Panel>
    <asp:panel Id="pnlCua"><asp:FileUpload(...)></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu solución con la comunidad